# What is the value of this game?

Tags: probability, markov-process

We have 3 black and 2 red balls in an urn. If we pick a black ball, we lose 1 USD.  If we pick a red ball we win 1 USD. We can chose to start the game or not. If we start the game we can stop after every pick. 
I don't know how to calculate the value of the game.

Comment: We can maximize the expected value by walking away. And as a bonus we get some exercise.

Comment: Which color wins and which loses? You have "black ball" in both winning and losing cases.

Comment: Sorry, edited. Red ball wins.

Comment: I assume value is the expected value of winnings to the player?

Comment: Yes, it is the expected value.

Comment: Are the balls replaced after picking them?

Comment: No, we don't replace the balls.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Surprisingly, this is not true, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a computational approach using dynamic programming.

Consider a function $V : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $V(b, r)$ is the value of a game with $b$ black balls and $r$ red ones.  What do we know about $V$?

- $V(0, r) = r$.
- $V(b, 0) = 0$, since if there are no red balls left we should walk away.
- For $b, r > 0$, we consider what will happen if we draw at least one more ball.  If on our next draw we draw a black ball, we lose $1$ and are left with $b-1$ black balls and $r$ red ones, so we expect to gain $-1 + V(b-1, r)$ in total.  If we draw a red ball, our total is $1 + V(b, r-1)$ by similar reasoning.  We weight these cases according to their probability to get the expected value, $\frac{b}{b+r}\left(-1 + V(b-1,r)\right) + \frac{r}{b+r}\left(1 + V(b, r-1)\right)$.  However, if this expression is negative, we should quit without drawing another ball.  Thus we get $$V(b, r) = \max\left(0, \frac{b}{b+r}\left(-1 + V(b-1,r)\right) + \frac{r}{b+r}\left(1 + V(b, r-1)\right)\right)$$

We can use the above facts to fill in a table of values of $V(b, r)$ for $b \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $r \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
 & b=0 & b=1 & b=2 & b=3 \\
\hline
r=0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
r=1 & 1 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
r=2 & 2 & 4/3 & 2/3 & 1/5 \\
\end{array}
$$

So with $3$ black balls and $2$ red ones, the game is worth $1/5$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the recursion part?

Comment: @kanbhold Yes, see my edited answer.

Comment: Nice that you took the time to fill the table :). Wow, it is a bit counterintuitive that the game is actually profitable even if $r<b$; no wonder I couldn't find the simple proof that it can't be profitable!